# Textarea disabled и IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, textarea

Доброе время суток!

Проблема: в ИЕ при textarea disabled, если background-color не равно white, то текст "выделяется" - происходит обводка (? или попытка сгладить) текста.
На компе в глаза не сильно бросается, но на мобилах шрифт словно раздваивается...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    textarea:disabled { 
        background-color: #1b2024; 
    color:red;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>  
    <textarea disabled="disabled">FKDJHKLHhhhhhhhhhhhhhfgjgj</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

[Здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/qZGHK/) можно посмотреть.

Как исправить? Можно, конечно, сделать div'ом, либо убрать disabled, а сверху наложить div, но хотелось бы именно через CSS убрать в IE эту гадость...

Comment: На stackoverflow был похожий вопрос, там человек после часов гуглинга пришел к выводу что эту гадость в IE убрать не получится

Comment: Смотрю на десктопном IE11 и не вижу проблемы... Что не так-то?

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну так вы дату поста посмотрите, тогда IE10 еще толком-то не вышел, а вы про IE11 пишете. И проблема сильно проявлялась на мобилках (WinPhone), как сейчас там дела обстоят не знаю - мы с некоторого времени не поддерживаем его.

Comment: Ой.. Вопрос-то на первой странице был, я на дату даже и не смотрел...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, управлением занимается браузер. разные браузеры по-разному отображают затемнение, IE вот еще добавляет такую тень.

ИМХО, проще будет реализовать свой элемент. Например div, который стайлить как захочется, если надо будет раздизейблить, то заменить его на обычный textarea...

Comment: Че-то я стормозил, и вы не подсказали - а мне зачем вообще disabled? Меня и readonly устроит - а там нет этого выделения... Но поскольку вопрос был именно про disabled, и вы на него более полно ответили, то приму ваш ответ)

Comment: У disabled атрибутов есть одна фича:

    Tip: Disabled <input> elements in a form will not be submitted.

Если readonly годится по смыслу, то можно и его использовать. Вы правы.

Answer (score 0):

```
:disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Или лучше сразу использовать [godlike.css](https://github.com/1000tech/godlike.css) для решения подобных проблем.